# Refresh entities in JPA

Tags: java, jpa, jpa-2.0

I'm confused about how I should refresh the state of entity that is already in the database. Being more specific, suppose I have "entity" persisted with a code like this:

```
EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
em.getTransaction().begin();
em.persist(entity);
em.getTransaction().commit();
entityManager.close();
```

Since I closed the EntityManager my entity instance is detached. Now suppose that I have other objects using this instance of entity. If I want to fetch the new state of this entity from the database, I pretty much can't use em.refresh() because the entity is detached. The em.merge() method returns a managed instance, and since is not the same instance of my object this can be a problem. I can foresee two solutions:

1. create a new method in my entity object that updates its state using a given entity instance.
2. not close the entity manager (implications !??)

So, what I should do in this case? How can I refresh the state of my entity object without losing all the references from other objects to it? Ideas?

Comment: More information about what you're trying to do and why you care that this specific instance be kept current might be helpful.  In general you're better served by using an in-memory L2 cache and just using entityManager.find() than trying to maintain that yourself.  There are also options to broaden the scope of your EntityManager to fit your unit of work.

Comment: I have a singleton model and my application is distributed. I would like to aware about any change  in other clients that were persisted to the database, so I can update my model instance. However, I can't afford to lose my entities instances since other parts of the program could be using that (e.g., a tree view).

Answer (score 1):

If entity A references entity B that is detached, merging B returns B', and refresh B'. If you merge A, A will change its reference of B to B'.

```
A ---> B --(merge)--->B'
                    (refresh)
                    /
merge A -----------/
```

Answer (score 0):

To avoid the changes being made to an entity by refreshing & getting detached after persisting, can implement the `Cloneable` interface & then processing the cloned entity accordingly.

```
//---

XEntity cloneX = (XEntity) entity.clone();

cloneX = entityManager.merge(cloneX);/* Persisting & getting synchronized copy */ 
// entityManager.refresh(cloneX); /* not need */

cloneX.copyTo(entity); // Add required changes back to entity if any

//---
```